# path.node().getTotalLength() hangs the browser

Tags: javascript, svg, path

I'm trying to generate a line chart but I'm getting errors trying to get the length of an svg path with the function getTotalLength(). This is strange to me because Firefox 19.0.2 runs fine but Safari 6.0.2 and Chrome 25.0.1364.160 hang.

The code where the error occurs is as follows:

```
          function displayValueLabelsForPositionX(xPosition) {
            if (typeof jsondata.length == 'undefined') {
                return;
            }

            // position label values
            var pathEl = path.node();     
            var pathLength = pathEl.getTotalLength();

           (...)
         }
```

The error always occur in the call to pathEl.getTotalLength() and the path seems to be correct, but is 150KB long:

```
<path class=​"line" d=​"M0.0020634675065341434,384.8476217601823C0.002751290008712191,384.8476217601822,0.0034391125108902388,384.8476217601822,0.004126935013068286,384.8476217601823C0.0048147575152463346,384.8476217601822,0.005502580017424381,384.8476217601822,0.006018446894057917,384.8476217601823C0.006534313770691453,384.8476217601822,0.006878225021780477,384.8476217601822,0.61216202693

(...)

1006.9979365324934,312.1617772714327" clip-path=​"url(#clip)​">​</path>​
```

Any idea ? Is there any other way to get this length without this function ?

Regards,
Joan

Comment: This more simple path hangs as well: &lt;path class=​"line" d=​"M5000,5000 C4970,5018 5129.5,4917.5 5099.5,4967.5"&gt;

Answer (score -1):

**There can be two different problems with this function:**

```
var pathLength = pathEl.getTotalLength();  // Causes reflow of document!!
```

**1. The problem might be, that this function is called many times, which
will cause a document reflow every single time.**

A solution could be to calculate / approximate the length of the path yourself.
That works good if the path is rather simple and you understand how it's being built.

[image: Possible simple paths]

You can try to approximate the path length by using the Theorem of "Pythagoras" (*wow I never thought I'd need that in programming!*) or other geometric formulas to get close to what you need. It's in any way much faster than using getTotalLength().

**2. The problem might be that your path is very complex (150kb)**

In case of that you can try to simplify your path by using a SVG Minifier / Simplifier like the one from [Peter Collingridge SVG Minifier](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser) or others.

Comment: 1. SVG doesn't have reflow. 2. This question was really documenting browser bugs nearly 10 years ago. These have been fixed in Chrome and Firefox and neither browser has had such hangs for many years now. The hangs were caused by having too many passes in the length calculation that didn't converge.

Comment: SVG elements cause reflow in Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (Current Version) e.g. when you use setAttribute, or getTotalLength(). We are currently experiencing that exact issue since one of the recent updates.
In Firefox there is no reflows though and our svg models load 1000x faster.
These problems have been around for years and are only problematic if you deal with a lot of SVG-elements.